# Horizontal dropdown sub-menu doesn't appear when x-axis overflow is hidden

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a bootstrap dropdown sub-menu button. I've found [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/tk7cnmwu/2/) by google search. I need this button scrollable. So, I've added this class:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-dropdown">
  <li></li>
</ul>

.scrollable-dropdown {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
```

But, after adding this, sub-menu is not showing.

[Here is the fiddle with problem](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/tk7cnmwu/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Use overflow: auto;

It works but only that will not leave the menu in a much better state (looks wise). 
You should try to place the Submenu below the originating main menu option with probably a different css to make it understandable that it is a submenu.

Use this along with the overflow: auto.
Use position: relative and remove the top: 0;

```
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    position: relative;
    display:none;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-left-color:#fff;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

[This is the fiddle with the edit](http://jsfiddle.net/tk7cnmwu/6/)